# how to redirect url using custom logic in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect url using htaccess file from project root folder.

I can easily redirect url like [www.xyz.com/ar/contact](http://www.xyz.com/ar/contact) to [www.xyz.com/contact](http://www.xyz.com/contact) using this

`Redirect 301 /ar/contact/ /contact/`

but how to redirect url like this

[www.xyz.com/ar/shop/xyz.html](http://www.xyz.com/ar/shop/xyz.html) to [www.xyz.com/shop/xyz.html](http://www.xyz.com/shop/xyz.html)

I have tried this

`Redirect 301 /ar/shop/^(.*)$ /shop/$1`

`Redirect /ar/shop/^(.*)$ /shop/$1 [R=301,L]`

`Redirect ^/ar/shop/(.*) /shop/$1`

but it did't work.

Comment: The `Redirect` directive uses _prefix-matching_ and everything after the match is appended to the end of the target URL - so your first rule already does what you require. See the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use a regex based pattern in `Redirect` directive.  If you want to redirect everything that comes after `/ar/shop/` to  `/shop/` then just use a static pattern `/ar/shop/` .

```
Redirect 301 /ar/shop/ /shop/
```

This will redirect all URIs starting with `/ar/shop/` to `/shop/` . forexample `/ar/shop/foobar` will get redirected to `/shop/foobar` > .

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples only.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ar/(.*)/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1 [R=301,NE,L]
```